# How to filter SQL results by nspredicate date?

Tags: ios, date, nspredicate

I am trying to filter sql lite database results by date but I am awful at ios date and time objects and not really sure how to do that. How would you set the NSPredicate to filter result by today, last 7 days, last 30 days and last 90 days?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Example**

```
- (NSPredicate *)predicateForDateWithinLast30Days
{

    NSDate *currentDate = [NSDate date];// get the current date


    // get the date 30 days prior to current date

    NSCalendar *calendar = [NSCalendar currentCalendar];
    NSDateComponents *dateComps = [[NSDateComponents alloc] init];
    [dateComps setDay:-30];
    NSDate *date30DaysAgo = [calendar
          dateByAddingComponents:dateComps
          toDate:currentDate options:0];

    // create the predicate
    NSPredicate *last30DaysPredicate = [NSPredicate
          predicateWithFormat:@"dateToCompare > %@", date30DaysAgo];

    return last30DaysPredicate;
}
```

Comment: I needed something similar, except within the next 30 days. Modified a bit and worked great thanks!

Comment: Hi friends.. I'm new to predicate concepts.. I need to implement this concept.. i need my expenses to be filtered based on date.. When will this NSpredicate method will get called.. how to implement this..